# Gwt static resource from subfolders not found

Tags: gwt

I have a problem with path to javascript in my `GWT` html.

I get: `WARNING: No file found for: /smartajax/libs/historyjs/history.html4.js` and more like this

File exists in my `war/html1` dir.

It happens only if script like this above is called not from my Html1.html, but from other script that is in public (its not declared in html by `<script type="text/javascript" ...>`

```
 - public_res
  - smartajax
     - libs
         - historyjs


 - war
  - html1
     - smartajax
         - libs
             - historyjs
```

`<script type="text/javascript" src="html1/smartajax/load.smartajax.js"></script>`

How to solve this?

Comment: Where is the gwt app html file which adds <script type="text/javascript" src="html1/smartajax/load.smartajax.js"></script> and also put your gwt module package information in the above question.

Comment: Where is history.html4.js in your dir structure?

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally place all your third party scripts in same relative folder.

```
1) All in public/thirdparty
2) All in war/thirdparty
```

Answer (score 0):

Your gwt public resource folder is compiled into your module's folder, and not war base directory.  It will be compiled into war/module_name/html1/smartajax/...  So, instead of using relative uris, how about absolute uris?

GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() -> Base url for html page, http://x.y/

GWT.getModuleBaseURL() -> Base url for gwt module, http://x.y/module_name/